# How to calculate the correct characters the user typed

Tags: javascript

[Ask]

anyone know the reference for a case like this?
the user must type the word: "learn" -> total character 5
while the user types instead: "l3arn"

well I want to count the right word only, so the result 4

from google not yet find a solution, maybe someone knows the keyword/reference for the problem.

I want to implement it in javascript

Comment: `var userInput = "l3arn";` then `var correctCount = userInput.split('').filter(c => isNaN(c)).length;`

Answer (score 2):

You want to calculate the number of characters in the correct position?

In that case, it's a simple solution.

Javascript example:

```
function countCorrectCharacters(expectedString, string) {
  var count = 0;
  var l = Math.min(expectedString.length, string.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
      if (expectedString[i] === string[i]) {
          ++count;
      }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "learn";
var userInput = "l3arn";
var userInputArray = userInput.split('');
var counter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i< "l3arn".lenth(); i++){
 if(str.indexOf(userInputArray[i]) !== -1) counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to count the number of letters in a string? Use this:

```js
function getNumberOfLetters(string) {
  let match = string.match(/[A-Za-z]/g);
  return (match && match.length) || 0;
}

console.log(getNumberOfLetters("learn")); // 5
console.log(getNumberOfLetters("l3arn")); // 4
console.log(getNumberOfLetters("12345")); // 0
```

Comment: Is `string.replace(/[^a-z]/ig,'').length` just not enough characters to type? ;-) You might also consider `return (string.match(/[A-Za-z]/g) || []).length`. But I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @RobG Well, yes, that also works. I think the current method is better, because it does not need to create a useless array.

Comment: The "useless" array is only created if *string.match* returns null and saves an assignment and evaluation of the result of *match.length*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yes, but it is still created. I would prefer not to create any additional arrays when I can do it with a simple boolean operation.